# Election results have data and styling problems

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election

The moderator elections at C.SE ended, so the [election page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) now shows the results.

There is a styling problem with the result summary which causes the text to wrap oddly:

[image]

This can be cleaned up by using a clearing div/break after the last candidate nameplate:

[image]

Additionally, is it possible for 131 people to visit during the election but for 170 to visit the election page? Are stats counted before the election begins or after it ends, or is this an error?

Comment: [css.gif](http://imgur.com/Q3cUg29)